# Kendo TabStrip set Id for created tab

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have Kendo TabStrip and I add new tab like this

```
tabStrip.append({
                        text: name + "  <button data-type='remove' class='k-button k-button-icon' onClick='closeTab($(this).closest(\"li\"));'><span class='k-icon k-i-close'></span></button>",
                        encoded: false,
                        contentUrl: "/Info/Index?id=" + id
                    });
```

How can I set ID for this tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your append, set the id attribute:

```
tabStrip.tabGroup.children().last().attr("id", "myId" + tabsLength);
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/OJOPo/5